# Fuelux - How to populate repeater data using datasource

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I am trying to use [fuelux repeater](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#repeater) for one of my projects but I kind of struggle on populating data into the table. I used the basic repeater template given on the docs but couldnt understand [their example](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/repeater-examples.js) properly since its using a lot of other plugins like require.js and underscore.js. Can anyone please help me understand how to do this. Essentially I want use php and js to import data into the repeater.

I have a jsfiddle setup [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrcfh4b8/) with my current progress.

```
<div class="fuelux">
    <div class="repeater" id="myRepeater">
    <div class="repeater-header">
      <div class="repeater-header-left">
        <span class="repeater-title">Awesome Repeater</span>
        <div class="repeater-search">
          <div class="search input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="repeater-header-right">
        <div class="btn-group selectlist repeater-filters" data-resize="auto">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="selected-label">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Filters</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li data-value="all" data-selected="true"><a href="#">all</a></li>
            <li data-value="some"><a href="#">some</a></li>
            <li data-value="others"><a href="#">others</a></li>
          </ul>
          <input class="hidden hidden-field" name="filterSelection" readonly="readonly" aria-hidden="true" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group repeater-views" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-default active">
            <input name="repeaterViews" type="radio" value="list"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input name="repeaterViews" type="radio" value="thumbnail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="repeater-viewport">
      <div class="repeater-canvas"></div>
      <div class="loader repeater-loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="repeater-footer">
      <div class="repeater-footer-left">
        <div class="repeater-itemization">
          <span><span class="repeater-start"></span> - <span class="repeater-end"></span> of <span class="repeater-count"></span> items</span>
          <div class="btn-group selectlist" data-resize="auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="selected-label">&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="caret"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li data-value="5"><a href="#">5</a></li>
              <li data-value="10" data-selected="true"><a href="#">10</a></li>
              <li data-value="20"><a href="#">20</a></li>
              <li data-value="50" data-foo="bar" data-fizz="buzz"><a href="#">50</a></li>
              <li data-value="100"><a href="#">100</a></li>
            </ul>
            <input class="hidden hidden-field" name="itemsPerPage" readonly="readonly" aria-hidden="true" type="text"/>
          </div>
          <span>Per Page</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="repeater-footer-right">
        <div class="repeater-pagination">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm repeater-prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous Page</span>
          </button>
          <label class="page-label" id="myPageLabel">Page</label>
          <div class="repeater-primaryPaging active">
            <div class="input-group input-append dropdown combobox">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="myPageLabel">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"></ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control repeater-secondaryPaging" aria-labelledby="myPageLabel">
          <span>of <span class="repeater-pages"></span></span>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm repeater-next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next Page</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your supplied code is simply a copy from the Fuel UX docs.  Perhaps you should keep reading - maybe this example here: https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/repeater-examples.js

Comment: @jiy please read the description i said i used the template provided in the fuelux docs. I had to insert some code since stackoverflow requires a code when attaching jsfiddle links.

Answer (score 0):

The Fuel UX Repeater uses a JSON-based datasource. This means you will probably use AJAX to load a JSON file and then format that data and pass it to the datasource callback. You will need to set up the connection between the columns and the key/value pairs in the JSON array.

[Here is how the repeater in the docs is set up](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/repeater-examples.js). That JS and the HTML you have should be all you need. You do not need AMD/require.js for Fuel UX to work. [Here is an example of the use of script tags only](https://gist.github.com/interactivellama/abb3ca7f23d8b47cb1ee) if you download Fuel UX into a vendor folder.

Comment: I cant figure out how to do this without require.js. I removed all require stuff but it still gives this error: "define is not defined" for this: define(function(){

Comment: We are working on a non-require JSbin that should be added to the docs this week. https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/678#issuecomment-61345919